# Docker-compose: close ports after SIGTERM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker and Docker Compose for my development environment.

When I switch between projects, I usually have quite some pain because I receive a `PORT ALREADY IN USE` error.

If I do `docker-compose up` (which makes my rails server start), is `Ctrl+C` the correct way to terminate this container?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

Sometimes, I simply have to delete `./tmp/pids/server.pid`, but sometimes I have to `kill -9` some process.

Here's for example what `ps -edf | grep docker` outputs:

```
root       742     1  0 Jul18 ?        00:01:11 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://
root     22341   742  0 Jul21 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32781 -container-ip 172.17.0.48 -container-port 5432
root     22510   742  0 Jul21 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3030 -container-ip 172.17.0.49 -container-port 3030
root     28766   742  0 Jul21 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32783 -container-ip 172.17.0.57 -container-port 5432
root     28886   742  0 Jul21 ?        00:00:00 docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3000 -container-ip 172.17.0.58 -container-port 3000
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would launch the container as a background process with `docker-compose up -d`. Then later you can do a shutdown with `docker-compose stop` in a clean way.

Comment: Did not know about this. I'll try it and report! Thanks